# How to wrap span in jquery object

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery and have the following object properties by using the

```
map(function() { 
                return $(this).val();  //get the <checked>'s value
                }).get():
```

It returns the following object values:

["ABC", "ABD Curve", "TWER", "NBBDD", "KLF", "WERQ"]

I want to wrap span around each value , example :

```
<span class="selected_filter">ABC</span>
<span class="selected_filter">ABD Curve</span>
<span class="selected_filter">TWER</span>
<span class="selected_filter">NBBDD</span>
<span class="selected_filter">KLF</span>
<span class="selected_filter">WERQ</span>
```

how can I do this ?

UPDATE, Below is my FULL code : 
the $(this).val() will return the value of the selected checkbox

```
   function getCheckedValue(arr) {
    arr = $(".bf-c-1 input:checkbox:checked").map(function() { 
                return $(this).val();  //get the selected checkbox value
                }).get();

    return arr;
}


$( document ).ready( function( ) {


var checked_arr = [];

$(".bf-c-1 input:checkbox").each(function() {

        //Do stuff
                if (this.checked) {

                checked_arr = getCheckedValue($(this).val());
                console.log("checked:  ",this.id , checked_arr);

                }
});


$(".bf-c-1 input:checkbox").change(function() {

  checked_arr = getCheckedValue($(this).val());

  $("#checked_value").text(checked_arr.join(','));
});

$("#checked_value").text(checked_arr.join(' '));




});
```

@cr0ss ; UPDATE HTML :

```
<div id="checked_value"></div>

<div class="bf-attr-block">
<div class="bf-attr-header bf-attr-2">
Brand
<span class="bf-arrow"></span>
</div>
<input id="search_brand" type="text" placeholder="Search Brand" value="">
<div id="results" class="bf-attr-block-cont brands ">

<div class="bf-attr-filter bf-attr-2 bf-row">
<span class="bf-cell bf-c-1">
<input id="bf-attr-2-0" type="checkbox" value="18 And East" name="attribute_value[2][]">
</span>
<span class="bf-cell bf-c-2">
<label class="bf-attr-val" for="bf-attr-2-0">18 And East</label>
</span>
<span class="bf-cell bf-c-3"></span>
</div>

<div class="bf-attr-filter bf-attr-2 bf-row">
<span class="bf-cell bf-c-1">
<input id="bf-attr-2-1" type="checkbox" value="2nd Day" name="attribute_value[2][]">
</span>
<span class="bf-cell bf-c-2">
<label class="bf-attr-val" for="bf-attr-2-1">2nd Day</label>
</span>
<span class="bf-cell bf-c-3"></span>
</div>


<div class="bf-attr-filter bf-attr-2 bf-row">
<span class="bf-cell bf-c-1">
<input id="bf-attr-2-6" type="checkbox" value="Abaya Suraya" name="attribute_value[2][]">
</span>
<span class="bf-cell bf-c-2">
<label class="bf-attr-val" for="bf-attr-2-6">Abaya Suraya</label>
</span>
<span class="bf-cell bf-c-3"></span>
</div>


</div>

</div>
```

UPDATE: Possible to do this way ?

```
function displaySelectedFilter(arr){

                arr.each(function (item) {
                var span = $("<span>");
                span.attr('class', 'selected_filter');
                span.text($(this)[0].value);
                $("#checked_value").append(span);
                });

}

$( document ).ready( function( ) {

$("#search_brand").keyup(function(){

  var searchtext = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  console.log("stext: ",searchtext);
    $("label").each(function() {
     if($(this).text().toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchtext)==-1){
        $(this).parent().parent("div").hide();
      } else {
        $(this).parent().parent("div").show();
      }
    });
});

var result = [];
$(".bf-c-1 input:checkbox").each(function() {

        //Do stuff

        result = $("input[name='attribute_value[2][]']:checked");




});


$(".bf-c-1 input:checkbox").change(function() {

  result = $("input[name='attribute_value[2][]']:checked");
  displaySelectedFilter(result);


});


displaySelectedFilter(result);
```

Comment: post the whole script. What exactly $(this).val() returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eFmaY/)** to enlighten you.

Assuming you actually retrieve what you posted, it's quite easy. Don't forget to explicitly write the CSS for `selected_filter`.

This code just iterates over the object, create a jQuery instance of `span`, attaches the `css` and `text` and append to `div`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var result = ["ABC", "ABD Curve", "TWER", "NBBDD", "KLF", "WERQ"];

    result.forEach(function (item) {
        var span = $("<span>");
        span.attr('class', 'selected_filter');
        span.text(item);
        $("#div").append(span);
    }); 
});
```

**UPDATED:**

Here is the new **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eFmaY/2/)** considering your checkboxes, and not only the "object" you said you had.

Comment: I suppose the object generated by the $("#checked_value").text(checked_arr.join(','))

Comment: how come i get this message in the console ?  ReferenceError: span is not defined
 

return span;

Comment: What is the content of `arr`? I used `result` on the Fiddle

Comment: the checked_arr is produced by the function getCheckedValue

Comment: Update the answer with the HTML of your checkboxes.

Comment: OK, i have updated the HTML in the above

Comment: @redcoder updated the answer, check it out

Comment: can I group the span function as single function? Because I have two scenario, where by when pageload, it needs to generate the selected checkboxes (either by default or referrer page).Some checkboxes will be selected from the refereer page. I am thinking to use "each", then when user click the single box, will use the ".click"

Comment: i have updated my idea in the question section, see if this is possible ? The default selected checkboxes may have more than one selected.

Comment: @redcoder Yes, it is possible and that's quite easy. Just create a function and call it twice: on page load and on click/keyup

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

For each element returned:

```
.wrap('<span class="selected_filter"></span>');
```

Comment: who downvoted??? this is the perfect answer as the OP can use this right after .get()....

Comment: @C-link ok now we are having an array like this, `["ABC", "ABD Curve", "TWER", "NBBDD", "KLF", "WERQ"]` how do you utilize `.wrap()` in this context..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy check get() method api... the result is not actually like that...